# C Pthreads - Parent/Child process

Tags: c, pthreads, parent-child

I've written a C program that creates a child thread. After creating the child thread, the parent thread should output two messages. The first being "I am the parent" and the second "The parent is done". The same should occur for the child thread "I am the child" and "The child is done". However I want to make sure, the second message of the child is always done before the second message of the parent. How can I achieve this in my code below?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int status = 0;

void *print_child(void *arg)
{

    while (status == 0)
    {
        printf("Signal hasn't changed..\n");
        sleep(1);

    }
    printf("The child has started...\n");
    printf("The child is done! \n ");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, &print_child, NULL);

    sleep(2);
    printf("The parent has started...\n");
    printf("The parent is done! \n");

    status++;

    if (pthread_join(child, NULL))
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you create any processes, only threads. There's a big difference between processes and threads, and terminology matters.

Comment: Sorry I mean't thread.

Comment: As for your problem do some research for the standard thread synchronization primitives, like *semaphores* or *condition variables*.

Comment: It's just too look at Pthreads and how to use them. And thank you for the answer :)

Comment: The least thing you could try: make `status` atomic. (It's an optional feature of C11: [Atomic operations libary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).)

Comment: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/166129-understanding-pthread_cond_wait-pthread_cond_signal.html  check this out.

Comment: Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Comment: Please ask the other students to refrain from posting more copies to SO:(  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48785375/758133

Answer (score 1):

Once a thread created it process independently and act like a separate process from the main thread. In your case you are joining the child thread after the statement `printf("The parent is done! \n");`. It not necessary that operating system will complete the child thread first always. Hence your expected result might not meet always. put a long sleep statement just before statement `printf("The parent is done! \n");` and check but still not necessary that child will complete first.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you aren't making sure that the second printf in the parent thread is being executed before the second printf in the child thread.

A good option in this case would be to use mutexes. In this case, you can use a mutex to act as a 'guard' before the second printf, so the code will look something like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t print_lock;

...
```

In print_child:

```
// can only acquire after the parent releases, therefore guaranteeing that 
// the parent thread has already printed the second statement
pthread_mutex_lock(&print_lock); 
printf("The child is done! \n ");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_lock);
```

In main:

```
// lock it before the child thread is 
// started, therefore guaranteeing the parent will have initial ownership
pthread_mutex_lock(&print_lock); 
pthread_create(&child, NULL, &print_child, NULL);

sleep(2);
printf("The parent has started...\n");
printf("The parent is done! \n");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_lock);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put following line after `printf("The parent has started...\n");` and before `printf("The parent is done! \n");`:

```
status++;
if (pthread_join(child, NULL))
{
    printf("ERROR");
    exit(1);
}
```

So corrected code will be as following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int status = 0;

void *print_child(void *arg)
{

    while (status == 0)
    {
        printf("Signal hasn't changed..\n");
        sleep(1);

    }
    printf("The child has started...\n");
    printf("The child is done! \n ");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, &print_child, NULL);

    sleep(2);
    printf("The parent has started...\n");
    status++;
    if (pthread_join(child, NULL))
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("The parent is done! \n");
    return 0;
}
```